# Should I use a day= tag in my BiBTeX files?

Tags: bibtex

I've seen some BiBTeX files that have a `day=` tag. The problem is, most `.bst` files I've seen don't honor it.

For example, here is a BiBTeX entry:

```
@article{wsj-tjx,
 title="How Credit-Card Data Went Out Wireless Door",
 author="Joseph Pereira",
 year=2007,
 month=May,
 day=4,
 url="http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB117824446226991797",
 journal="The Wall Street Journal"
}
```

I've traditionally done this as:

```
@article{wsj-tjx,
 title="How Credit-Card Data Went Out Wireless Door",
 author="Joseph Pereira",
 year=2007,
 month=May # " 4",
 url="http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB117824446226991797",
 journal="The Wall Street Journal"
}
```

What's the right thing to do? If having a `day=` tag is the right thing to do, how do I handle `.bst` files that don't have one? Sometimes they are easy to modify, sometimes hard, but forking everybody's `.bst` file seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: In my opinion the best tool for bibliographies is `biblatex` in combination with `biber`. `biblatex` supports the field `day` and so I would use it. However if you use `biblatex` there are a lot of entry types which are not defined by the standard styles e.g. `online`.

Comment: A particular style will use the information required for that style. Putting 4 in the month is not a good solution as a bst which does use the day field will not recognise it as a day. If you need the day supplied, you want to use a bst which uses it. Most bibliography styles don't require the day but that doesn't mean there is no point in including it in your bib file because you might later want to use the entry with a bst which does use day. The same is true of biblatex, in fact: it supports day but whether day is used in formatting the bibliography depends on the style, as with bibtex.

Comment: `biber` is not an option with academic publishing, since many require bibtex as part of their back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the unfortunate answer is that there is no right thing to do, but the workable thing to do is to use `month=May # " 4"` unless you know for sure that your bst uses the `day=` field.